# Migrate Spring Security 4.x (ShaPasswordEncoder and unique salt for each user) to 5.x (BCryptPasswordEncoder)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am migrating Spring security from `4.2.16.RELEASE` to `5.6.3` version.
The existing project security configuration uses deprecated `ShaPasswordEncoder` and custom `SaltSource` for the salt generation. The salt is comprised of application configuration property and user's uuid:

```
     <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.my.security.CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="CustomUserDetailsService" />
        <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <property name="servicesURL" value="${custom.services.url}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="256" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="saltSource" class="com.my.security.UserSaltSource">
        <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="CustomId" />
        <property name="systemWideSalt" value="${security.systemwide.salt}" />
    </bean>
```

The `getSalt` method:

```
public Object getSalt(String secondSaltProperty) {
    try {       
        return secondSaltProperty + this.systemWideSalt;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(exception.getMessage(),
                exception);
    }
}
```

My goal is not only migrate to newer Spring security version but also start using the recommended `BCryptPasswordEncoder` password encoder.
According to the [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html), I have to migrate the existing passwords:

> The format is intended to work with the DigestPasswordEncoder that was found in the Spring Security core module. However, the passwords will need to be migrated to include any salt with the password since this API provides Salt internally vs making it the responsibility of the user. To migrate passwords from the SaltSource use the following:
> String salt = saltSource.getSalt(user);
> String s = salt == null ? null : "{" + salt + "}";
> String migratedPassword = s + user.getPassword();

**Question**: The thing that I am not clear about the password migration part is combining the new password storage format `{id}encodedPassword`, where `id` is used for selecting corresponding password encoder, and the salt part.
According to the [migration guide](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format) I have to add `{sha256}` prefix to the stored passwords, so the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` will pick up the proper decoder, but how to deal with the `salt` part then?

My understanding is the following:
First I have to define the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and if I don't add the `id` prefix to the password I have to set the default password encoder using `DelegatingPasswordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches` method to pick up the old password encoder.
Next, authentication logic is implemented in the custom `AuthenticationProvider` service class, in which `passwordEncoder` is injected and used for password matching  check. Before calling the `PasswordEncoder.matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword);`, I have to add the code that will format the encoded password to match the `{salt}password` format.

Next step is to add Successful authentication listener that will re-encode the passwords to match the `{bcrypt}password` format and store it into DB. So on the next user log in attempt the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` password encoder will be invoked instead.

Once all passwords will be migrated, I will be able to delete the custom SaltSource-wise stuff and the Successful authentication listener.

Pls, correct me if I am wrong or if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: imho you are overthinking this. The only thing you would need to do is configure the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to use your old encoded as a default, everything else can remain the same. For the migration part, if you want to do that you can do that in a listener, but that would be just an addition and nothing more.

Comment: Apart from the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and provide a default for the `MessageDiggestPasswordEncoder` you would need to include the salt in the password (which is afaik, the only thing you need to do next to the configuration of the encoder). So your passwords in the db should look like `{salt}sha56-hash` The salt is basically what you now do in your `SaltSource` and should now be included in the db/password.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the clarification. I did the configuration changes according to your instructions and everything works as expected. Will you add your comments as an answer and I will accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 2 things you need to do.

1. Migrate the passwords to include the salt in the pattern `{salt}<password-hash>`
2. Configure the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and set the, properly configured, `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` as the default. So if no encoding is specified it will fallback to that one.

If you want to convert the passwords on the fly you could do that with a succes handler and update the record to use BCrypt/SCrypt instead of what you have now.